# TTK detect button click

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a login frame class which I am adding to root window. What I want to do is to detect when a button is clicked from the login frame (marked in code as: #Detect login with username and password and quit button click here). The purpose of this is to keep the ui separated from the authentication method. How can I do it? Thanks is advance.

The code goes like this:

```
class LoginFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        login_frame = ttk.Frame(parent)
        login_frame.pack(pady=70)

        logo = ttk.Label(login_frame, text="Login")
        logo.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

        username = ttk.Entry(login_frame)
        username.grid(row=20, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        password = ttk.Entry(login_frame)
        password.configure(show="#")
        password.grid(row=30, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        login_btn = ttk.Button(login_frame, text="Login", command=self.authenticate)
        login_btn.grid(row=40, column=0, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        quit_btn = ttk.Button(login_frame, text="Quit", command=self.quit_app)
        quit_btn.grid(row=40, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        error_lbl = ttk.Label(login_frame, justify="center", foreground="#FF0000")
        error_lbl.grid(row=50, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

        username.focus_set()

    def authenticate(self):
        #return login button is clicked with username and password
        pass

    def quit_app(self):
        #return quit button is clicked
        pass

root = Tk()
root.config(background="light grey")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry("800x500")
lf = LoginFrame(root)

#Detect login with username and password and quit button click here

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: is there a reason you're not calling the constructor of the parent class in `LoginFrame`? (eg: `ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)`)

Comment: You are right. it should call the constructor of the parent class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking doesn't make sense. There shouldn't be any code between `lf = ...` and `root.mainloop()`. The wqy GUIs work is that you create widgets and bind commands to them, and then tkinter will call the commands when the widgets are clicked.

If you want something to happen after the user clicks the login button, associate a command with it, and put whatever code you want to execute in that command.

Answer (score 4):

You need it to have a command called a callback.

```
login_btn = ttk.Button(login_frame, text="Login")
login_btn.grid(row=40, column=0, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew", command=authenticate)
```

notice the new part `command=authenticate`

command can be set to any method

http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm

I'll let you figure out the quit button, I don't want to do everything, it helps to do some yourself.

Comment: I have added the command (I forgot the add it before). I know how to add the call back command. What I need is to detect the button click after lf = LoginFrame(root)

Comment: It won't allow you to click the button until you've called lf = LoginFrame(root) the frame wont be set up til then.

Comment: Can you suggest any alternative?

Comment: @huber.duber: Nothing will happen, GUI-wise, until `root.mainloop()` is called. While it is executing, `tkinter` will call commands associated with the various widgets (like buttons) when the user interacts with them. This is the common logic flow in most GUI programs.